# Django global variables with threading

Tags: python, django, multithreading, global-variables

I'm building a web-app to control some hardware connected to a Raspberry Pi.

The goal:

1. On server startup do some tasks once and store information globally (open COM Ports and store as objects)
2. On POST/GET call from a view start a thread with the serialports from 1) plus some data (names as Strings) from the POST/GET call. This thread is some game logic for the hardware and runs for around one hour each
3. Have possibility to terminate this thread anytime from a view and from within the thread
4. Have possibility to get variables from thread and display on web-app

At the moment I'm struggeling with the general design of this task. I'm new to threading and Django and can't quite tie these together. My Implementation right now only has a simple endless loop which should print out some debugging info if a global variable has changed.
On startup of the server, I'm starting a runner script in a new thread. The global var is stored in `cfg.py` and imported in `apps.py` and `views.py`. All three files are in the root directory of the app.

`cfg.py`

```
RUNNING = False
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Player
from . import cfg

def index(request):
    player = Player.objects.all()    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            print('got POST request')
            cfg.RUNNING = True 
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)

    return render(request, 'mygame/index.html', {
        'player' : player
        })
```

`apps.py`

```
import os
import threading
import datetime 
import time 
from django.apps import AppConfig
from . import cfg

class MyGameConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'mygame'


    def ready(self):
        run_once = os.environ.get('CMDLINERUNNER_RUN_ONCE')
        if run_once is not None:
            return
        os.environ['CMDLINERUNNER_RUN_ONCE'] = 'True'

        #### Code to execute on startup
        try:
            bp_thread = threading.Thread(target=runner, args=('John', 'James', ), daemon=True)
            bp_thread.start()
        except Exception as exc:
            raise exc

def runner(p1, p2, *args, **kwargs):
    # dummy function running in background
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    stroftime = starttime.isoformat()

    print(f'process started at {stroftime}')

    while True:
        if cfg.RUNNING:
            print('RUNNING = True')
            print('setting back to False for testing')
            cfg.RUNNING = False
        else: 
            pass

        time.sleep(1)
```

Why can't my `def index(request)` function change the val of the `cfg.RUNNING` var? I get the debugging print with *got POST request* but the runner function is not recognizing the changed state of `cfg.RUNNING`.
I also tried an aproach with `global RUNNING` without success. If it was only strings I have to pass I'd use the model database but since the serial ports are objects I can't store in the SQLite3 db, this doesn't seem to suit my needs. Also the vals should be reset on server restart.

Maybe my whole design is flawed and I'm open to any suggestions to achive my goal. Thanks a lot in advance!